# Component based vs full stack framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I don't understand what these 2 words mean.

I think `symfony` is a full-stack framework while `yii` is a component-based framework.

Is this correct?

If so, what are the main differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

full-stack frameworks (symfony) you use the entire stack.

component frameworks (zend) you pick and choose what libraries you want.

Answer (score 0):

Component framework may also refer to visual components as in Widgets.